# How to automate linting, testing and file generation in python?

Tags: python, build, continuous-integration

I'm sure this is answered somewhere else, but I can't for the life of me find it!

I have some python files and I want to automate the linting, testing and running of them. This is going to be part of a CI dependency chain, and I know how I would do this in e.g. Jenkins.

However the problem is that I would like developers to be able to run the above change locally before they push changes to the remote repository. I have come from a C++ team where we used team and I'm used to running something like:

```
scons test
```

That would run the linter, the tests, and maybe then output some files.

How can I replicate this functionality on a Python code base? I realise I could do this with a bash script or something, but it seems that there should be a standard build tool to do this. Thanks!